# Javascript variable must access one time to be able to access it's value

Tags: javascript

I am working on a Firefox extension and using "Web Storage API" which I can't access the taken data before accessing it, eg with `alert();`

Here is the code that returns the inappropriate data:

```
function getSettingFromStorage(item) {
        browser.storage.local.get(item).then(token => {
            return token[item];
        });
    }
    alert(getSettingFromStorage('something')); // returns ''undefined'
```

Working code:

```
function getSettingFromStorage(item) {
            browser.storage.local.get(item).then(token => {
                alert(token[item]); // returns 'undefined'
                return token[item];
            });
        }
alert(getSettingFromStorage('something')); // returns the appropriate value!
```

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: `browser.storage.local.get(item)` is asynchronous. The `alert` only helps because it will allow some time to tick while you go and press the OK of the popup, which will make the async operation finish but the rest of the code execution is waiting for the prompt to be dismissed.

Comment: add a `return` keyword _before_ `browser.storage...` and call the function as: `getSettingFromStorage('something').then((value) => console.log(value))`

Comment: Also i think the comments in your second code example are not correct; `alert` inside the function will show the appropriate data whereas the `alert` after the function will still show `undefined` because your function does not explicitly return anything.

Comment: @Yousaf thanks, it worked!
But I test it after 2 seconds too, I mean I used `setTimeout()` but that didn't help, Was my code wrong again?

Comment: _Was my code wrong again?_ - yes. Execution of `getSettingFromStorage` function will finish _before_ data is read from the storage and its result is available to your code. The callback function of `then` method will be invoked _after_ the execution of `getSettingFromStorage` function has ended.